# Is asking to proof read text for a specific issue on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I understand I can't just ask a proofreading question.

I want to ask a question if I am using dialog tags well.  I see a lot of discussion about it, but I can't understand is my writing makes the mistakes mentioned in many answers. I want to post a writing sample and ask if this sample handles the tags well.

Would this be on topic?

Answer (score 4):

No. A good stack exchange question is one that may be of interest to other people. It may be about the problem you are trying to solve, but it should be phrased as a general problem to which people can give general answers. "Am I doing it right?" is not such a question.

But a question along the lines of "Is X a good way to do dialogue tags?" would be on topic. To get there, figure out the pattern you are using in dialogue tags and ask a question about that pattern. You can, and should, illustrate the pattern with examples from your work.